# Install and Configure laravel-echo and pusher-js in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I'm using laravel-echo and pusher-js in a projetct with Laravel and VueJS and it works.
But now I need to broadcast in a VueJS project without laravel (a pure VueJS project).
I don't know how to install and configure laravel-echo and laravel-pusher in a pure project VueJS.
I try to do llike this, but don't works:

```js
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: "pusher",
  key: "myappkey",
  cluster: "mt1",
  host: window.location.hostname + ":6001",
});

Vue.use(Echo);
```

The 2 packages are in my package.json:

```
"laravel-echo": "^1.11.2",
"pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pusher is not just a Laravel plug in. You should be able to use the pusher-js library directly and can get up and running by following the [quick start](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/getting_started/javascript/).

You will need to trigger events and can do so using one of the many server libraries detailed on the [Pusher site](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/channels_libraries/libraries/#official-server-libraries).